# Can you bring home 2 kittens (siblings) at 8 weeks?

Tags: cats

I know the general consensus is 12-14 weeks, but we want to bring home 2 siblings from the same litter, and the litter we found won't be 12 weeks for another 2 months. We really want to get them home as early as possible to bond with them before my girlfriend starts university. I work from home and she's worried that if we're not both at home for the first few weeks that the cats won't see her as part of the family since she leaves every day and I don't.

**TL;DR:** If we bring home 2 siblings from the same litter a bit early, would they be better off than if we only brought one?

Comment: this is a duplicate question so i am commenting on what is not answered there,your girlfriend dont need to worry about the bonding of the cats as cats usualy bonds whith new people very quick.two cats from the same litter is usualy best.

Comment: @JamesJenkins my apologies, despite my relentless efforts to dig up info on this particular situation, that question didn't pop up. I agree it is pretty much a duplicate.

Comment: @trondhansen thanks for answering the 2nd part, that is great to hear.

Comment: @Jeff no need to apologize; your question will (I assume) be marked as a duplicate and help people in the future by making that one more searchable.  (They might find yours instead and then follow the link.)  Meanwhile, you get answers faster because it's already been asked.  On the specific concern, I adopted 12-week-old littermates when I was living alone and working full-time, and they still bonded with me just fine.